# If a series diverges, dividing it by the sequence of partial sums preserves divergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_n $ be positive, $s_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i $         and  the series $\sum x_n$ diverges.

I'm trying to see how we can prove the following two propositions withouth using anything related to Cauchy ( Cauchy criteria for series and notion of cauchy sequences ) or too advanced but i can't seem to suceed in finding a way.

The propositions are :

a) $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{x_{n+i}}{s_{n +i}}   \geq  1 -  \frac{s_n}{s_{n+k}}$

b) The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{s_n} $ diverges

Thanks in advance

Comment: Interesting propositions... May I ask you where are they coming from?

Comment: It's coming from Rudin's Book

Answer (score 5):

For problem $(a)$, notice that $s_{n+k}\geq s_{n+i}$  for $0\leq i\leq k$, so that $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{x_{n+i}}{s_{n+i}}\geq\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{x_{n+i}}{s_{n+k}}=\frac{1}{s_{n+k}}\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_{n+i}=\frac{1}{s_{n+k}}\left(s_{n+k}-s_{n}\right)=1-\frac{s_{n}}{s_{n+k}}.$$

**Hint:** Try to use part $(a)$ to solve part $(b)$.

Comment: Dumb question... Could not $s_n$ be oscillating? Just in general terms? Otherwise very nice way of showing it :)

Comment: @Umberto: The question states that the $x_i$ are positive, so no $s_n$ cannot be oscillating.

Comment: Sorry... Just noticed that :)